# How to raise an error when trying to delete referenced row

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, cascading-deletes

I'm actually working with sqlalchemy and I use the automap mechanism to generate my classes. I have a question about the deletion policy of this ORM : How can I do to make my programm raises an error when I try to delete a row which is referenced?

My foreign reference is a `NOT NULL` constraint which means sqlalchemy set the `ON DELETE` policy to `CASCADE`.

I see in the documentation that there are two `CASCADE` policy :

- `delete` -> columns set to NULL if parent deleted
- `delete-orphan` -> rows deleted if parent deleted

Actually, I don't want sqlalchemy to manage the `ON DELETE`. I want that my database raised an error. Because for now, when I delete a row referenced, there is a deletion on cascade which is made by sqlalchemy, thing I don't want at all. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What server are you using? Do you have the column marked as a foreign key?

Comment: I'm using a Postgresql database with a Python server based on Flask and SQLAlchemy. And yes my columns are well marked as a foreign key in my database and with the ON DELETE NO ACTION argument.